# can't return a result table using procedure with CI

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

this is the first time I'm using procedure in mysql and I'm not good enough with CI, I want to make procedure to show content of my table, and here's my procedure;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `TestNewProcedure`()
BEGIN
      select * from app_tablet;
END;
```

when I tried run with mysql it works fine, but I want to call it call it from my model with CI I got an error, here's my code for controller;

```
    public function tes3(){

        $data['rows'] = $this->menu_model->selectQuery("call TestNewProcedure()");
        $this->load->view('xml_view',$data);
    }
```

and here's the code from model

```
    function selectQuery($query){
        return $this->db->query($query)->result();
    }
```

and this is error message that I got;

```
Error Number: 1312

PROCEDURE myDB.TestNewProcedure can't return a result set in the given context

call TestNewProcedure()

Filename: /var/www/newfolder/models/menu_model.php

Line Number: 13
```

I want to show content of my table using procedure, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("call TestNewProcedure()");
return $query->result();
```